# PHP variable has a number, how do I get numbers before that starting with 0

Tags: php, arrays

I have this variable `$day = 5;` I am looking to turns this into an array like this

```
$array = array(0 => 0, 1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, 4 => 4, 5 => 5);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: "is this possible?" PHP is Turing-complete, which means that literally anything is possible (given unlimited memory).

Comment: PHP is the zombo.com of languages?

Comment: And this is seriously getting upvotes?

Comment: I love questions like this; one word answers: ***yes***. Now please change your question to ask how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = range(0,$day);
```

Old, 1-based solution:

<del>$array = array_combine(range(1,$day),range(1,$day);</del>

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but didn't the OP ask for a zero-based range?

Comment: I did ask for 1 at first, but then edited to 0, thought it would be easier, but I guess not

Comment: It is just replace `1` with `0` in `range` function.

Comment: @Kolink: hehe, it wasn't earlier.... but I'll edit it to comply to the current question... :)

Comment: Ah, okay. Makes sense. Although personally I'd have used: `array_combine($x = range(1,$day),$x);`

Answer (score 3):

Look into the [`range()`](http://php.net/range) function.